# Rails 4, reload lib/ directory in developer mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

What to add configuration in Rails 4 for reload lib/ directory if file changed in developer mode?

Comment: The lib directory is the directory containing the gems data when you run bundle its automaticly reloaded the next time you start the server if you have a webserver running you need to restart it if you added new gems or installed another version.

Comment: I this case, it used for store custom library in lib/ directory.

Comment: But thats not what its made for. Either you make a gem out of it or you move it to the place libraries belong to,... which ist app/model/ form models,... app/helpers/ for model independent methods,...

Comment: But where to place code, if i want to extend String class for example? I common case where to place code witch don't contain primary business logic without extracting code to independent gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to extend classes is coding a gem. If you dont want to code a gem because the effort is oversized you can monkeypatch the classes by placing your code in the `initializers` folder. But both wont solve your problem because gems and initializers are only loaded once. When you want code that is reloaded after every change you have to place it in your `app` directory. You could place your code in a helper that includes itself in the classes you want to extend.

Comment: How about this https://github.com/plataformatec/responders ? "Responders only provides a set of modules, to use them, you have to create your own responder. This can be done inside the lib folder for example", in developer mode if code changed without reloading server, always raise error.

Comment: Why do you want to place your code in the `lib` directory so bad?^^ You can place your code in a helper...^^